# Multiple attachments in MS Access 2010?

Tags: windows-7, ms-access

I'm trying to create a Web form with Access where the user inputs their info and can upload 2 picture attachments.

The result I am getting when creating the database says I can't have more than one attachment on the Web.

Verbatim:
The Web does not support multiple attachment columns.

Doesn't seem likely that a user is limited to only one attachment and I really need them to be able to upload 2 photos.

Any suggestions? Noob to Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason I can think of that would stop a user from adding or having “many” attachments for a given record and web form you display.

However, if the web form is displaying the attachment as a picture, then you ONLY will see the first picture in that form (or row if you using a continues form) WHEN running as WEB.

Running the web form in the Access client (desktop), you will see some navigation arrows and can “navigate” to view all pictures.

HOWEVER IN BOTH CASES (running that form as desktop or web), you can add or delete or download a given attachment.

A web form with an attachment column looks like this:

[image]

Perhaps you not using a attachment column, but the above is how a form looks with a attachment column added to the form. Note how above you can simply "click" on the text box, and then see the Add New Attachment popup box. This box lets you add, delete, or download to view existing attachemnts. As noted ONLY the first picture attachment will auto display in the web form.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for such a late reply. I tried this and it worked. Odd thing for me is I don't get the attachment button like you have. I have to double click the box and then a window pops up. It just doesn't look like the 'normal' upload I am used to seeing around the Web.